# 行かせる means "send" rather than "make someone go"

Tags: causation

行かせる - Make someone go

I saw this sentence, "息子を公立学校に行かせてください" and it seems to translate to "Please **send** your child to a public school" instead of "please make your child go to a public school". The question is, why does the causative form of 行く translates to "send" instead of "make someone go"

Comment: Who said so in what situation? It depends on that.

Comment: Would the translation "have someone go" vs "make someone go" help?

Comment: Try not to get too hung up on the English translation.

Comment: @AeonAkechi I get what you mean, but in this case, "send" vs "make someone go" has quite a difference in meaning. The former being just sending someone (without pressure) whilst the latter, actually forcing someone to go. In other words, if I were to say this exact sentence to someone, the second meaning will make me sound rude but not the first

Comment: @donburi Why don't you clarify the situation? I want to downvote this question if I have the privilege.

Comment: Interestingly, the causative in German overlaps with the permissive in a way that's a bit similar to Japanese. If I say _"Ich lasse Karl gehen"_, I'm saying **both** _"I **make** Karl go"_ (causative) and _"I **let** Karl go"_ (permissive). Which one I mean depends on the context, but at the basic level without any context, it's basically the same thing: "I", through action or inaction, am causing "Karl" to go. In the sample sentence, the unstated subject, through action (causative) or inaction / acquiescence (permissive), is causing the 息子 to 行く to 公立学校.

Comment: Sending a child to school is the same thing as making them go to school basically so this question seems like a confusion about English more than anything. Also where does the translation come from? I've downvoted this because I think the question is very poor.

Comment: @Ben Making someone go to school is forced. Sending is not

Comment: I agree that there is something of a difference in "make someone go" in that it implies force.  As such, I don't think that's generally a good translation for the causative form at all, because causative usually doesn't have that sense of forcing someone to do something against their will (there are other constructs for that if you mean that specifically), but really just means "make it so that *(something happens)*", which I think is usually better translated as "let someone go" or "have someone go".  So I think the whole premise of this question is based on a wrong assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take this 「せる」 as the causative or imperative form, but the context determines which. It is a bit complicated.

According to [コトバンク](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B-549042):

> 相手が自分の思うようにするよう。また、ある事態が起こるようにしむける意を表す。

「息子を公立学校に行かせてください」 : "Please make your child go to a public school"

Your son might want to go to a private school for some reason. In this case, you can't allow him to go there. So, you might be asking the teacher to persuade him to go to a public school.

---

In another scenario,

> （「せていただく」「せてもらう」の形で）相手方の許しを求めて行動する意を表す。「言わ**せて**いただく」「やら**せて**もらう」

It is asking someone for a permission to do something (If the situation were special, it might be making allowance to do something.).

So, 「息子を公立学校に行かせてください」 means *"Please let my son choose to go / allow my son to go to a public school"* In this case, the teacher might be stopping your son from going to a public school.